# Epic FHIR AppOrchard OAuth

Tags: oauth, hl7-fhir, epic

How can I get Auth Token from AppOrchard? Is there an easier/better method than below?

"https://apporchard.epic.com/interconnect-aofeb18prd-oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080&client_id=myID&state=abc123";

Background:
I have a Client ID from AppOrchard and have a Client App (Standalone Launch) in test that is able to obtain needed data from the 
Epic FHIR Sandlot.  But issues with OAuth2 test not receiving an Auth Token.

The FHIR Client app (a Windows Desktop app, .NetCore, NOT a Web app)  I am using
Visual Studio Express C# 2017 & 2019 with NuGet Packages for FHIR DSTU2 (Core,ElementModel,Serialization, Support.Poco,FhirPath).

For the OAuth2 from Epic I am using Systen.Net.Http.HttpClient:
HttpClient MyHttpClient = new HttpClient();

For the Sandlot data I used HL7.Fhir.Rest.FhirClient: getting Bundles back which I then loop thru for data.
public FhirClient client = new Hl7.Fhir.Rest.FhirClient(@"https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2");

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing a lot of the right steps, but it is hard to tell with getting into more of the details of your client ID set up, etc.

I would suggest reaching out to the apporchard@epic.com email address - they can help dive in to your specific issue, with your specific client ID, and get you connected with the right folks/experts at Epic.

Hope that helps,
Danielle

Comment: Please share the resolution.  Thanks